# How to delete a complete row that don't have any primary key or ID

Tags: mysql

[Screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U6iU9.png)

I have a table where it has some rows without any primary key or Id. How can I delete it by using multiple conditions in sql query?

Comment: PK presence is not compulsory for the deletion. You must use WHERE condition(s) which completely identifies the row(s) to be deleted.

Comment: @Akina a pk per se is not necessary, just a combination of fields that are unique to the record(s) you want to delete.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_delete.asp
Simply add all conditions needed to identify the item
The best way to test the conditions it to try it first on a `SELECT`

```
DELETE FROM schedules WHERE COMPANYNAME = "TravelOnTip" AND AVAILABELSEATS = 50 AND FROMLOCATION = "BEN-SG";
```

Comment: Please do not refer to w3school in the questions which are tagged as MySQL-related - this site uses MS SQL syntax, so not all its statements are applicable to MySQL. Refer to MySQL Reference Manual.